# var_dump on GROUP_CONCAT query not working

Tags: php, mysql, group-concat

I'm trying to print a value from a group_concat query, but for some reason, the code keeps failing. If I print the array that contains my value, I am able to see that everything is being fetched correctly. But when I try to access the first element in the array, my page gives me a white screen. Why is this happening?

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
 $db->setQuery("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( FieldValue )
FROM tpro_rsform_submission_values
WHERE FieldName
IN (
'LAST NAME', 'FIRST NAME'
)
GROUP BY SubmissionId");

$result = $db->loadObjectList();
foreach ($result as $r) {
        echo var_dump($r);
}
// </code>
```

The following is the result for my var_dump($r)

[image]
but when I try to do a var_dump($r[0]), my page gives me a white screen.

Similarly, when I try to access the field through `var_dump($r['GROUP_CONCAT(FieldValue)'])` I still get a white screen. How do can we access the field?

Comment: It's object, not array and properties of object can be retrieved like $object->property. In your sql add 'as groupc' and then call $r->groupc;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the field an alias -

```
$db->setQuery("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( FieldValue ) AS whatever
```

and then

```
echo var_dump($r->whatever);
```

I am not sure why you're using `$result = $db->loadObjectList();` though. You could use any of the array methods and it would be better/easier for what you're trying to do. Then you would say:

```
echo var_dump($r['whatever']);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your result type is an Object - not an Array.

So, you should access it using `->propertyName` and not `['propertyName']`.

The Array way is working, but you should reserve that for arrays - so you can clearly idenify - without looking at the object type - if you are currently using an array or object.

Second, it seems like your Access attempt is missing the whitespaces arround `FieldValue`. However, it would make sence to give your concatenation an alias, which you can access without having special characters in it.

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
 $db->setQuery("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( FieldValue ) AS myColumn
FROM tpro_rsform_submission_values
WHERE FieldName
IN (
'LAST NAME', 'FIRST NAME'
)
GROUP BY SubmissionId");

$result = $db->loadObjectList();
foreach ($result as $r) {
        echo var_dump($r->myColumn);
}
```